XSLT 1.0 copy and remove node
I´ve to copy a node (Set_Item/ForwarderReferenceNumber) in case of mupltiplied and than remove the node "Set_Item" where we have taken the value from.
To find the same Set_Item (but different ForwarderReferenceNumer) we have to use "Set_Item/GTIN").
-> So in my example, we can see that "GTIN" of "LineNum" 2 and 7 is identical (555) and now we have to copy the "Set_Item/ForwarderReferenceNumber" from Line 7 below the "Set_Item/ForwarderReferenceNumber" of Line 2 and than remove the complete node of "Set_Item" with "LineNum" 7.
example of XML:


<OSTRPT>
  <LineInformation>  
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>2</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>      
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>     
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>666</ForwarderReferenceNumber>  
      <Date>2</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>7</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>     
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>      
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>777</ForwarderReferenceNumber> 
      <Date>3</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OSTRPT>



This should be the correct output:


<OSTRPT>
  <LineInformation>  
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>2</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>      
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>     
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>666</ForwarderReferenceNumber>
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>777</ForwarderReferenceNumber> 
      <Date>2</Date>      
    </Set_Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OSTRPT>



Here is my current xslt. (But no solution for this case)


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">   
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//LineInformation[not(Item)] and //LineInformation[not(Set_Item)]"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="not(//Set_Item) and not(//Item)"></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="concat(../LineNum, '|', Text)"/>
  <xsl:key name="allowance_charge_header" match="AllowanceOrCharge_Header" use="concat(Code, '|', Amount)"/>
  <xsl:key name="allowance_charge_line" match="AllowanceOrCharge_Line" use="concat(../LineNum, '|', Code, '|', Amount)"/>
  <xsl:key name="packing_slip" match="ItemDeliveryInformation" use="concat(../LineNum, '|', PackingSlipId, '|', DeliveryDate, '|', DeliveredQuantity)"/>
  <xsl:key name="item" match="Item" use="concat(LineNum, '|', GTIN, '|', SupplierArticleNumber, '|', Quantity)"/>
  <xsl:key name="set_item" match="Set_Item" use="concat(LineNum, '|', GTIN, '|', SupplierArticleNumber, '|', ForwarderReferenceNumber)"/>
  <xsl:key name="WeightAndVolume" match="WeightAndVolume" use="Weight_RecId"/>
  <xsl:key name="ContainerInformation" match="ContainerInformation" use="SSCC_RecId"/>
  <xsl:key name="ContainerInformation_Set_Item" match="ContainerInformation_Set_Item" use="SSCC"/>

  <!-- Identity-Template für die nicht explizit benannten Elemente -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Forwarder/Code[//Forwarder/Country = 'DE' and //Forwarder/Name[contains(., 'GLS')]]">
        <Code>5</Code>       
    </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Entfernt alles nach und inkl. "_" -->
  <xsl:template match="GLN[contains(., '_')]">
    <GLN><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '_')"/></GLN>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Entfernt alles nach und inkl. "_" -->
  <xsl:template match="Recipient[contains(., '_')]">
    <Recipient><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '_')"/></Recipient>
  </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="ItemDeliveryInformation_Set_Item">        
        <xsl:element name="ItemDeliveryInformation">       
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Set_Item">        
     <xsl:element name="Item">
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RFF_Line_Set_Item">        
     <xsl:element name="RFF_Line">
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
      <xsl:template match="ContainerInformation_Set_Item">        
     <xsl:element name="ContainerInformation">
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

  <!-- Differenz zwischen bestellter und gelieferter Menge -->
  <xsl:template match="Item/ItemDeliveryInformation[. != '']">
    <xsl:copy>
    <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <QtyDifference>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number((./DeliveredQuantity - ../Ordered), '#0.00')"/>
    </QtyDifference>  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <!-- das aufzurufende Template: OrderResponseReference Teil 1-->
<xsl:template name="last-substring-after">
  <xsl:param name="search"/>
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="result" select="substring-after($string, $search)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($result, $search)">
            <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
            <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$result"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- das aufzurufende Template: OrderResponseReference Teil 2-->
  <xsl:template match="OrderResponseReference[contains (., '/')]">
    <OrderResponseReference>    
        <xsl:call-template name="last-substring-after">
        <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'/'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </OrderResponseReference>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="OrderResponseReference[not(contains (., '/'))]">
    <OrderResponseReference><xsl:value-of select="." /></OrderResponseReference>    
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="HeaderText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="LineText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('line_text', concat(../LineNum, '|', Text))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="AllowanceOrCharge_Header[generate-id() != generate-id(key('allowance_charge_header', concat(Code, '|', Amount))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="AllowanceOrCharge_Line[generate-id() != generate-id(key('allowance_charge_line', concat(../LineNum, '|', Code, '|', Amount))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="ItemDeliveryInformation[generate-id() != generate-id(key('packing_slip', concat(../LineNum, '|', PackingSlipId, '|', DeliveryDate, '|', DeliveredQuantity))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="Item[generate-id() != generate-id(key('item', concat(LineNum, '|', GTIN, '|', SupplierArticleNumber, '|', Quantity))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="Set_Item[generate-id() != generate-id(key('set_item', concat(LineNum, '|', GTIN, '|', SupplierArticleNumber, '|', ForwarderReferenceNumber))[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="WeightAndVolume[generate-id() != generate-id(key('WeightAndVolume', Weight_RecId)[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="ContainerInformation[generate-id() != generate-id(key('ContainerInformation', SSCC_RecId)[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="ContainerInformation_Set_Item[generate-id() != generate-id(key('ContainerInformation_Set_Item', SSCC)[1])]" />

  <!-- Delete 0 at PackagingQty -->
  <xsl:template match="PackagingUnit[PackagingQty = '0.00' or AllowanceOrChargeAmount = '0']"/>

  <!-- Delete 0 at ContainerInformation/SSCC_RecId -->
  <xsl:template match="ContainerInformation/SSCC_RecId"/>
  
    <!-- Delete 0 at ContainerInformation/SSCC_RecId -->
  <xsl:template match="ContainerInformation_Set_Item/SSCC_RecId"/>

  <!-- Delete 0 at WeightAndVolume/Weight_RecId -->
  <xsl:template match="WeightAndVolume/Weight_RecId"/>
  
<!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>



Here is the example with duplicate lines:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OSTRPT>
  <LineInformation>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>4</LineNum>
      <GTIN>4251431238524</GTIN>
      <SupplierArticleNumber>95003G4103VS</SupplierArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>
      <StatusDescription>Ware versendet</StatusDescription>
      <StatusChangeDate>2024-04-04T14:47:56</StatusChangeDate>
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>090028350002745490</ForwarderReferenceNumber>
      <ReferenceDate>2024-04-04T14:47:56</ReferenceDate>
    </Set_Item>   
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>4</LineNum>
      <GTIN>4251431238524</GTIN>
      <SupplierArticleNumber>95003G4103VS</SupplierArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>
      <StatusDescription>Ware versendet</StatusDescription>
      <StatusChangeDate>2024-04-04T14:48:06</StatusChangeDate>
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>090028350002745513</ForwarderReferenceNumber>
      <ReferenceDate>2024-04-04T14:47:56</ReferenceDate>
    </Set_Item>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>4</LineNum>
      <GTIN>4251431238524</GTIN>
      <SupplierArticleNumber>95003G4103VS</SupplierArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>
      <StatusDescription>Ware versendet</StatusDescription>
      <StatusChangeDate>2024-04-04T14:48:06</StatusChangeDate>
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>090028350002745513</ForwarderReferenceNumber>
      <ReferenceDate>2024-04-04T14:47:56</ReferenceDate>
    </Set_Item>    
  </LineInformation>
</OSTRPT>



Thank you!
best regards
Julian

I wasn't able to follow your explanation. Is it possible this is a grouping problem?

I think that also can help me. In my xml i get the same Set_Item twice (if a GTIN is the same on different nodes - that means this is one and the same article)
But i need it just once.
But the value of different ForwarderReferenceNumber is not identical on both Lines where the GTIN is identical.
So, thats why Ive to copy it first, before deleting duplicate lines.

Consider reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

done. I thought it´s better to add some more nodes, you you can see that there could be additional segments.

It is indeed a grouping problem, look for "xslt grouping muenchian method"

yes, but please i need help to create it into a correct way.

Use a key and process all ForwarderReferenceNumbers in a "group" formed by that key:


const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="group" match="Set_Item" use="GTIN"/>

<xsl:template match="Set_Item[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', GTIN)[1]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="ForwarderReferenceNumber">
  <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('group', ../GTIN)/ForwarderReferenceNumber"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;

var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(domParser.parseFromString(xslt, 'application/xml'));

var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml').text, 'application/xml'));

console.log(resultDoc);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc));
<script id="xml" type="application/xml">
<OSTRPT>
  <LineInformation>  
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>2</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>      
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>     
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>666</ForwarderReferenceNumber>  
      <Date>2</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>7</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>     
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>      
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>777</ForwarderReferenceNumber> 
      <Date>3</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OSTRPT>
</script>



If you need to eliminate duplicates from the ForwarderReferenceNumber as well, use a second key:


const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="gtin-group" match="Set_Item" use="GTIN"/>

<xsl:key name="gtin-ref-group" match="Set_Item" use="concat(GTIN, '|', ForwarderReferenceNumber)"/>

<xsl:template match="Set_Item[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('gtin-group', GTIN)[1]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="ForwarderReferenceNumber">
  <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('gtin-group', ../GTIN)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('gtin-ref-group', concat(GTIN, '|', ForwarderReferenceNumber))[1])]/ForwarderReferenceNumber"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;

var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(domParser.parseFromString(xslt, 'application/xml'));

var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml').text, 'application/xml'));

//console.log(resultDoc);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc));
<script id="xml" type="application/xml">
<OSTRPT>
  <LineInformation>  
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>2</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>      
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>     
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>666</ForwarderReferenceNumber>  
      <Date>2</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>7</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>     
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>      
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>777</ForwarderReferenceNumber> 
      <Date>3</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
    <Set_Item>
      <LineNum>7</LineNum>
      <GTIN>555</GTIN>     
      <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
      <MeasureUnit>PCE</MeasureUnit>
      <DeliveryDate>2024-03-13</DeliveryDate>
      <Status>24</Status>      
      <ForwarderReferenceNumber>777</ForwarderReferenceNumber> 
      <Date>3</Date>          
    </Set_Item>
  </LineInformation>
</OSTRPT>
</script>




thank you very much, in general it looks good. but if the node "Set_Item" is multiplied with the same "ForwarderReferenceNumber" in XML then I get multiplied value of "ForwarderReferenceNumber" with the same content.
I just need the content just once - hopefully you understand my question
I add an example in my question above
